# Why Question looks like more valuable than Answer

Tags: discussion, support

I don't want to make quarrel or anything trouble, but actually I random watch profile of some users and it seems they get more scores from their Question than their Answer, not all, but it's a general condition.

I don't deny valuable Question is important, but if Question is easier for user to get score, I think it may hit enthusiasm of people who do more hard work on Answer.

Please don't vote on this question... just one suggestion is that more reasonable to distinguish score from Answer and from Question ?

Comment: Don't let the pretty numbers fool you to the left of a question - they only count for half of an answer's reputation.  To that point, I've noted that tons of question upvotes is actually quite *rare*, almost to the point that there's maybe < 2,000 questions that really could get to be that valuable.

Comment: thanks a lot guy, just some complains, I will continue to work to answer questions.

Comment: @OneKitten actually i don't mean Question in one item has more votes than Answer, i mean some people get more score from their Question part than Answer part, actually an extradionary example is one user has about 40 questions and no answer, while question gives him really high score. I am sorry and I don't want to make quarrel or any unrespect to any people.

Comment: Just as an observation, I see a lot more high rep users with no questions asked than no answers posted. As for the user you saw, I personally find that the exception, not the rule. Most of the people I see with most of their rep from questions tend to actually have a ton of lower-rep questions (as in score < 2), and maybe only a couple (if any) higher-rep questions.

Comment: @OneKitten I know one vote on Answer is bigger than that on Question, so I think it may be confused after my question is reedtied now, it's not what I mean before, I just doubt the score system to reward Answer than Question.

Comment: @DennisMeng thanks, I don't make a full survey and it's got from random watch as my question described, I just think it will be more reasonable to distinguish between score from Question and score from Answer.

Comment: "Please don't vote on this question" - on Meta Stack Overflow, voting doesn't give any reputation.

Comment: @xfix sorry, actually it's my first time to ask question in Meta Stack Overflow and I don't know rule here. I just don't want to make a quarrel here

Comment: -1 for "please don't vote".  Have to try to get it back to 0. :P

Comment: Honestly, I think SO needs more good questions more than it needs more good answers. And I say this as someone with almost 100K rep from answers and something like 20 from questions. (Note that I said _good_ questions; we obviously don`t need more duplicates, unanswerable nonsense, etc.) So if someone is getting more points from asking great questions than he is from answers, that's not a help vampire, that's exactly the kind of user we need more of.